# Textfield in HTML doesn't change its value, need a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of HTML code:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<td><input type=text value="hello"></td>
<td><input type=text value="George"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="return getValues();">
```

And JS (Jquery) code:

```
function getValues(){
    var inputs = $('#mytable').find("input");   
    for (var u = 0; u<inputs.length ; u++){ 
        $(inputs[u]).parent().html($(inputs[u]).attr("value"));
    }

    return false;
}
```

So basically on button click I want to search for all the inputs and replace them with their values.
But HTML does not dynamically update value of textfields, so I can type whatever I want but it will always produce table with "hello" and "George". I want to remove textfields, but keep their actual "value", not the one saved in the attribute.

**Something like textfield.getActualText(), because Jquery attr("value") returns the value, which was assigned when the page loaded.**
Hope you know what I mean.
The textfields don't have names because they do not need them, JS would remove them anyway.

Comment: you dont close the input tag ... by the way, you are looking for `$(element).val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.val()` instead of `.attr()`, since .attr() will only return the initial value that the input element was set with. And you don't need to use `for` loop to iterate over a set of elements wrapped as a jquery object, you can simply use `.each()` function of jquery to iterate it.

Try,

```
$('#mytable').find("input").each(function(){
 $(this).parent().html($(this).val());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hdYM3/)